# sharepoint 2013 created site with ipad sometimes a few javascript file not loaded

Tags: javascript, ipad, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, master-pages

We have a site created with sharepoint 2013. When I open site from ipad sometimes  afew js file not loaded. This cause error in home page.

I included js file in masterpage like;

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/SiteAssets/script/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript" src="/SiteAssets/script/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js" ></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/SiteAssets/script/XXX.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/SiteAssets/script/AAA.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/SiteAssets/script/YYY.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/SiteAssets/script/ZZZZ.js"></script>
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What's the error? Have you checked the logs using the correlation id?

Comment: There wasnt any server err. It was just jquery error. When it could not load jquery the problem happenned. ı solved it with combining js files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got information about request number is limited with two for js files and js requests blocks all other request.

There were many assets(image,js,css) link in my master page. 
So I tried to combine the js files and decrease the number of request for js files in two.

This solved my problem.

Descrease the number of requests as you can.